# What are the differences between :wq<cr> :x<cr> and ZZ when exiting vim?

Tags: save, filesystem, quit, original-vi

Vi and Vim, as all of you know, have many synonyms. There are three ways I know of to save the file and exit Vim and Vi. These are *:wq* **<cr>**, *:x* **<cr>** and *ZZ*. I have heard that these are different in some way.

Are there any practical differences between using:

<kbd>:</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd><cr></kbd>

<kbd>:</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd><cr></kbd>

or

<kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>

to save file and exit Vim and Vi?

Comment: The simple answer:  they are the same.

Comment: They are *not* the same.  I don't know the difference exactly, but it is something about writing vs. not writing to the file if no changes have been made (i.e. updating the timestamp).

Comment: Also, from a *practical* point of view, `ZZ` (or `ZQ`) is shorter and easier to type ...

Comment: `:help :wq`, `:help ZZ`, `:help :x`. It's right there in the docs.

Comment: @Antony I don't use this command enough, thanks!!

Answer (score 55, accepted):

From Vim's documentation, [`:x`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#%3Ax) and [`ZZ`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#ZZ) are equivalent; they only save the file if it has been modified, then quit Vim:

```
Write current file, if modified, and quit (same as ":x").  
(Note: If there are several windows for the
current file, the file is written if it was modified and the window is closed).
```

[`:wq`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#%3Awq) on the other hand writes the file and quits Vim (assuming proper permissions).

Answer (score 30):

As akshay pointed out, Vim's documentation explains, that `:x` and `ZZ` are equivalent and only save a file if the associated buffer has been changed. 
Whereas `:wq` saves the buffer to the corresponding file, even if it is unchanged.

In both cases, the contents of the buffer will be saved to disk. Obviously the outcome is the same, so why bother, right? But wait... There is a subtle, but not irrelevant difference.

If you exit Vim via `:x` and there has been no change to the buffer, there will be no change to the modification time of that file. On the other hand, if you quit via `:wq`, the modification time will change, as the file is technically rewritten (saved again).

This can have some impact in certain situations. For example a backup process that is dependent on modification time, could store this file (and potentially send it over the network) even if no additional information has been included. Or some monitoring process could ring an alarm if it detects that (for it) the file has been changed...

Edit: I forgot to mention, in order to leave an modified buffer/file without changing the modification time, a `:q` (without the `w`) will work, too.

Comment: Also, some autocommands will run only when the file is written. They won't run if the file hasn't changed and Vim is quit with ZZ or :x.

Comment: Another thing to mention is If you have unmodified buffer open in vim and you have deleted the file from your system, ZZ will not create the file and write to it.

Comment: It should be accepted answer

Comment: For what it's worth, ZZ saves some typing (vimgolf) because you don't have to type the <CR>.

Comment: The Z key is also right next to Shift on both QWERTY and Dvorak.

Comment: I love `ZZ` (save and exit) and `ZQ` (save without exit). It's fast and efficient. Is there a way to save a file without exit in a similar fashion though?

Comment: I don't know of a native VIM command for this but I'd just create a normal-mode mapping in your vimrc like `noremap ww :w<CR>`. This way you can just press `ww` during normal mode and save the file without quitting.